# Environmental variables ignored for Layout in Area

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a problem in my ASP.NET Core MVC application.

**Can anyone advise why the tag helper for environment (names) isn't working for my (administration) layout page when located inside an Area?**

When referencing my scripts using the below code, it works when placed into the Standard _Layout.cshtml page but not a _Layout.cshtml contained within an area (used for an administration area).
I am ideally trying to modularise my code into Areas - the dashboard contains this _Layout.cshtml page for the administration area.

I discovered that all my css/js references were being included (unminified and minified and CDN).  So I put the below code into public layout and admin layout.

```
<environment names="Development">
  Development
</environment>
<environment names="Staging,Production">
  Staging production
</environment>
```

**~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml** (public)

"Development" is displayed (good)

**~/Areas/Dashboard/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml** (administration)

"Development Staging Production" is displayed (bad)

**My environmental variable is**
ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT (with a value of Development)

**My start up**

```
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables();

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        // For more details on using the user secret store see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=532709
        builder.AddUserSecrets();
    }

    Configuration = builder.Build();
}
```

**Configure method**
...

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(name: "areaRoute",
                    template: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}");

    routes.MapRoute(name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

Any help would be great - thank you.
Dan.

Comment: Is the _ViewImports.cshtml that references the tag helper in the folder of the area?  Might need to be.

Comment: I love you! Added a _ViewImports.cshtml and imported taghelpers reference. Add as answer and i give big happy green tick!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like the tagHelper is not getting registered in the Area and is being processed by the browser.

TagHelpers like `environment` have to be referenced in your `_ViewImports.cshtml` file, which by default will just be in `/Views` but also should exist in each of your areas.